# Преобразование строки в число в определённой системе счисления и наоборот

Tags: c++, калькулятор

У меня стоит задача написать обычный калькулятор, но он должен поддерживать режим работы в двоичной, восьмеричной и 16-чной системах счисления. Сейчас для всех операций я считываю из TextBox строку и преобразую её в число, всё прекрасно работает.

```
string str;
MarshalString(H->Text, str);
double F_N = stod(str);
MarshalString(C->Text, str);
double S_N = stod(str);
```

Но я не могу понять, как мне вводить и выводить данные в определённой СС. Прошу, помогите решить данную проблему.

Comment: [`from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars)?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex

Comment: @ВадимЕрмаков - а Вам для вещественных чисел?

Comment: Да, пока только вещественные числа

Comment: тогда Вам нужно будет сделать это самостоятельно.